# How to create a semi transparent shape?

Tags: c++, opencv, shapes, alpha-transparency

I would like to know how to draw semi-transparent shapes in OpenCV, similar to those in the image below (from http://tellthattomycamera.wordpress.com/)

[image]

I don't need those fancy circles, but I would like to be able to draw a rectangle, e.g, on a 3 channel color image and specify the transparency of the rectangle, something like

```
rectangle (img, Point (100,100), Point (300,300), Scalar (0,125,125,0.4), CV_FILLED);
```

where `0,125,125` is the color of the rectangle and `0.4` specifies the transparency.
However OpenCV doesn't have this functionality built into its drawing functions. How can I draw shapes in OpenCV so that the original image being drawn on is partially visible through the shape?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The image below illustrates transparency using OpenCV. You need to do an alpha blend between the image and the rectangle. Below is the code for one way to do this.

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("IMG_2083s.png"); 
    cv::Mat roi = image(cv::Rect(100, 100, 300, 300));
    cv::Mat color(roi.size(), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 125, 125)); 
    double alpha = 0.3;
    cv::addWeighted(color, alpha, roi, 1.0 - alpha , 0.0, roi); 

    cv::imshow("image",image);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for your patience, but I solved it in another way, using the function addWeighted. Like this: 

cap >> img; 
img.copyTo (copy); 
rectangle (copy, Point (100,100), Point (300.300), Scalar (0,125,125), CV_FILLED, CV_AA, 0); 
addWeighted (copy, 0.4, 0.1 to 0 .4,0 img, img);
imshow("img",img);

Comment: @Bull, i had a query, you are not using `image` Mat object in `addWeighted` function call, how is it updating to image? Thanks

Comment: @Prakash The data in `roi` is a rectangular slice of the data in `image`. That is, if you read from `roi` you are reading from `image`, if you modify `roi` you are also modifying `image`.

Comment: How would one do this for any arbitrary shape or polygon?  I tried this `cv::Mat roi = image(cv::Mat(points));` (where `points` is a vector of cv::Point) but it didn't work.

Comment: @OliviaStork, easy way would be use answer of Alexander Taubenkorb and replace call to cv::rectangle() by code to draw arbitrary shape in overlay.

Comment: @Bull I tried that, I tried drawing an arbitrary shape by creating a cv::Mat from from a vector of cv::Point.  It didn't work.  Can you get it to work?

Comment: I got it working. I have added it as an answer. Let me know if anyone faces any difficulty.

Answer (score 20):

In OpenCV 3 this code worked for me:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread("IMG_2083s.png");
cv::Mat overlay;
double alpha = 0.3;

// copy the source image to an overlay
source.copyTo(overlay);

// draw a filled, yellow rectangle on the overlay copy
cv::rectangle(overlay, cv::Rect(100, 100, 300, 300), cv::Scalar(0, 125, 125), -1);

// blend the overlay with the source image
cv::addWeighted(overlay, alpha, source, 1 - alpha, 0, source);
```

Source/Inspired by: http://bistr-o-mathik.org/2012/06/13/simple-transparency-in-opencv/

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Alexander Taubenkorb's answer, you can draw random (semi-transparent) shapes by replacing the `cv::rectangle` line with the shape you want to draw.

For example, if you want to draw a series of semi-transparent circles, you can do it as follows:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread("IMG_2083s.png");  // loading the source image
cv::Mat overlay;  // declaring overlay matrix, we'll copy source image to this matrix
double alpha = 0.3;  // defining opacity value, 0 means fully transparent, 1 means fully opaque

source.copyTo(overlay);  // copying the source image to overlay matrix, we'll be drawing shapes on overlay matrix and we'll blend it with original image

// change this section to draw the shapes you want to draw
vector<Point>::const_iterator points_it;  // declaring points iterator
for( points_it = circles.begin(); points_it != circles.end(); ++points_it )  // circles is a vector of points, containing center of each circle
    circle(overlay, *points_it, 1, (0, 255, 255), -1);  // drawing circles on overlay image


cv::addWeighted(overlay, alpha, source, 1 - alpha, 0, source);  // blending the overlay (with alpha opacity) with the source image (with 1-alpha opacity)
```

Answer (score 1):

For C++, I personally like the readability of overloaded operators for scalar multiplication and matrix addition:

```
... same initial lines as other answers above ...

// blend the overlay with the source image
source = source * (1.0 - alpha) + overlay * alpha;
```